# jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278074/alert-with-jquery-on-button-click but when I try to comment or click the Solution thingy nothing happens(?). I had forgot a "

However, I now have

```
$("input[value='OK']").click(function() {
  if ($("input[title='Start Date']").val().length < 1)
  {
    $("input[title='Start Date']").val('Required field');
    return false;
  }
  if ($("input[title='Target Date']").val().length < 1)
  {
    $("input[title='Target Date']").val('Required field');
    return false;
  }
});
```

If both start date and target date are empty it adds "required field" to the start date textbox and then reloads the page. Why isn't return false working and instead of adding required field to the target date textbox it reloads the page. If I have a start date and no target date it adds required field to the target date textbox and then reloads.

Ultimately I want to add something like `<br/><span class="validate">Required field</span>` after the datetime picker.

Any ideas?

I can some mod add Aardsquid's answer to my other question as the right answer?
Thanks

Edit: for some reason I can edit my question but not post comment nor click the Correct Answer thingy.

the ID of the form is aspnetForm so I should have something like

```
$('#aspnetForm').submit(function ()
{

    if ($("input[title='Start Date']").val().length < 1)
    {
        $("input[title='Start Date']").val('Required field');
        return false;
    }
    if ($("input[title='Target Date']").val().length < 1)
    {
        $("input[title='Target Date']").val('Required field');
        return false;
    }
    if ($("input[title='People Picker']").val().length < 1)
    {
        $("input[title='People Picker']").val('Required field');
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
);
```

?

Comment: You should update or revise the same question if it's related...post a new one only if it's, well...a different question.  Also make sure to accept answers on your question via the check-mark beside the one that helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking into the form's "submit" event instead of the OK button's "click" event.

That is, (assuming you have only the one form: change the selector otherwise)

```
$("form").submit(function() {
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should return true if it passes, but that's another issue.

Is it throwing an error on the javascript console? Try running it in the Firebug javascript debugger.